# Table View in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android. I need the table view functionality as in iOS. iOS Table View has a selection functionality. How to implement this functionality in Android?

I have created a list view on one of the tabs with the list populated from an array but now on the particular list item click I want to load the new class and also have to perform new activity please guide me for this.
here is my code

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a table view is on the iphone, but it sounds like a TabHost will do what you want. Take a look at the [Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the List you need to add **OnItemClickListener** with the ListView object.

In the method you can start new activity e.g

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent n = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);

    //You can pass data to new activity if any
    //n.putExtra("data", "This is my data");


    startActivity(n);
}
```